# Как открыть проект на микросервисах в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Пробую открыть проект на микросервисах в Eclipse.
[oauth-rest](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/oauth-rest)

С Eclipse до этого не работал, а в IDEA все было просто - создаешь обычный java проект и добавляешь туда модули и получалось как единый проект.
В Eclipse так не работает. Попробовал добавить все единым каталогом, он распознал все проекты как просто набор каталогов, а не как проекты maven.
Попробовал добавить в workspase как набор отдельных проектов, он их определил, но именно как отдельные проекты.

[image: project]

И при компиляции выдает ошибку.
Например, имеется сервис

```
<artifactId>oauth-authorization-server</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Он используется в другом сервисе,

```
<groupId>com.baeldung</groupId>
<artifactId>keycloak-custom-providers</artifactId>
```

через зависимости в файле Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.baeldung</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth-authorization-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

И в результате компиляции получаю ошибку:

```
Failed to execute goal on project keycloak-custom-providers: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.baeldung:keycloak-custom-providers:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.baeldung:oauth-authorization-server:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Т.е. он не находит сервис oauth-authorization-server
Я так понимаю, что проблема в том, что он не видит общего pom.xml.
Но как это победить?